# Where can i find the definitions for the SQL Server functions (CONCAT, LAG)?

Tags: function, sql-server-2008

I am implementing a simple data-warehouse on over 100 clients which all have an application database. Some customers have SQL Server 2008 which precludes my scripts from referencing CONCAT and LAG.

Initial thoughts on how to resolve this are:

1. Find the definitions for these functions and apply these definitions as UDF's on the SQL 2008 instance. (I can imagine this working for CONCAT, but not for LAG).
2. Write my own UDF's. (Time constraints).
3. Replace the CONCAT references with the '+' operator and wrap the fields in an  ISNULL function. (Doesn't solve the LAG issue).

I think i could replicate LAG's behavior, but i suspect it would take some time to make it perform effectively against millions of rows of data. The builds recur during the night so speed is not the highest priority.

Comment: They are compiled into the .exe file. I very much doubt you can extract them

Comment: AHWNN - This is unfortunate, if this is the case i must consider options 2 or 3. Are you able to recommend publicly available UDF's for the purposes of CONCAT/LAG written for arbitrary data-sets.

Answer (score 0):

***LAG*** **Incompatibility:**

I replaced the use of LAG by using ROWCOUNT to identify the order of rows and used a sub-select to reference the same data set in the latter part of my CTE to look back to what was the previous row by time for a partitioned block of rows.

**This is a simplified illustration:**

```
`CTE xyz(
    SELECT [Field 1]
    , [Field 2]
    , [Year]
    , [Period]
    , ROWCOUNT(PARTITION BY [field 1], ORDER BY [Year] ASC, [Period] ASC) [Row]
    FROM table
    ) 
SELECT *
, (SELECT [Field 2] FROM xyz x1 WHERE x1.[Field 1] = [Field 1] AND [Row] - 1 = x1.[Row]) [Old row] 
FROM xyz`
```

***CONCAT* Incompatibility:**

I used the historic '+' operator to join VARCHARs and catered for NULLs using ISNULL because i wanted to include what data did exist.

```
SELECT ISNULL([Field 1], ''), + ISNULL([Field 2])
FROM table
```